# I have two small samples of different populations. How do I test if the population variance (not mean) of one is smaller than the other?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, small-sample

So, samples *a* and *b*; for simplicity's sake suppose that the sample variance of *a* is less than *b*, and my null hypothesis is that the population variance of *A* is not greater than that of *B*.

I am not concerned with the population means of *A* or *B*; they could be the same or they could differ. (However, in my application they should be very similar, so if I can only get a solution if I assume equal means, then that's better than nothing.)

The sample sizes are also very small (*n* = 5 currently). I can get more data, but the process is tedious, so *n* < 30 is a given. To further complicate matters, I can't guarantee that the sample sizes will be equal.

It's been a while since stats class, but I don't recall ever covering anything like this.

Comment: NB: It's invalid to formulate the null hypothesis based on the data and test it with the same data.  Thus, assuming your concern always has been about comparing the population variances, the null should be the the variances are equal and the alternative should be that they differ.  The right test to use depends on your assumptions about the population distributions: when they are reasonably close to Normal you can use Normal-theory tests (based on the F ratio statistic) but otherwise need some other test.  What, then, can you tell us about the likely population distributions?

Comment: @whuber: I chose the null hypothesis I did because the original, informal question was about identifying if one population had a lower variance than the other. So if the sample with greater variance came from the population of lesser variance, then that's as much of a fail-state as the two population variances being equal. As for the distributions, I really don't know since the values are the product of a complex computer program with several black-box components - both samples are generated by the same algorithm from the same data, though, so they should at least be roughly the same shape.

Comment: "If one population has a lower variance" means exactly the same thing as "the two variances differ," because one has to be lower, doesn't it?  The importance of this phrasing is that it introduces a factor of two in the p-value of the test.  Knowing the distributions have a common shape is very useful.

Comment: Okay, the original question is more like a compound of two independent questions: "does population A have lesser variance than population B?" and "does population B have lesser variance than population A?" Common sense would say that it's probably impossible to conclusively say that the sample with greater variance came from the population with lesser variance, though.

Answer (score 1):

The sample sizes can be different, but balanced designs with equal
sample sizes for A and B are more efficient. For example, if you
have resources to do get 40 observations overall, you will have
a better chance of detecting true differences if you have 20
observations from A and 20 from B than if you have 10 from A and
30 from B. That said, efficient or not, the tests *can* be done when sizes are unequal,
and I will use unequal sample sizes that are somewhat unequal in my example.

**Normal data.** Suppose you have 15 observations from A distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=4)$ and 10 observations from B $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=7).$
If you *know* that data are normal, then you can use a two-sided F-test
of $H_0: \sigma_A = \sigma_B$ against $H_a: \sigma_A \ne \sigma_B.$

[Often these are written in terms of ratios, because some of the statistical
tests use ratios: $H_0: \sigma_A/ \sigma_B = 1$ against $H_a: \sigma_A/\sigma_B \ne 1.$ The interpretation of test results is the same either way.]

Below is output for such a test from Minitab statistical software.

```
Test and CI for Two Variances: A, B 

Method

Null hypothesis         σ(A) / σ(B) = 1
Alternative hypothesis  σ(A) / σ(B) ≠ 1
Significance level      α = 0.05

F method was used. This method is accurate for normal data only.

Statistics

                                  95% CI for
Variable   N  StDev  Variance       StDevs
A         15  4.076    16.617  (2.984,  6.429)
B         10  7.520    56.555  (5.173, 13.729)

Ratio of standard deviations = 0.542
Ratio of variances = 0.294

95% Confidence Intervals

                            CI for
         CI for StDev      Variance
Method       Ratio           Ratio
F       (0.278, 0.971)  (0.077, 0.943)

Tests

                       Test
Method  DF1  DF2  Statistic  P-Value
F        14    9       0.29    0.040
```

95% confidence intervals are used. The F-test gives a P-value of 0.04,
so we can reject $H_0$ and conclude there is evidence of unequal
standard deviations (or variances) between A and B.

Whether the difference
between $\sigma = 4$ and $\sigma = 7$ is of *practical importance* is
for you to decide as you plan sample sizes. If sample sizes were much
smaller than 15 and 9, we may not have seen a statistically significant
difference above.

**Non-normal data.** There are several alternative 'nonparametric' tests for use on non-normal data. Two of them, due to Bonnet and to Levene, are implemented in Minitab.
Output follows, using the same data as before:

```
Test and CI for Two Variances: A, B 

Method

Null hypothesis         σ(A) / σ(B) = 1
Alternative hypothesis  σ(A) / σ(B) ≠ 1
Significance level      α = 0.05

Statistics

                                  95% CI for
Variable   N  StDev  Variance       StDevs
A         15  4.076    16.617  (2.497,  7.655)
B         10  7.520    56.555  (4.139, 16.994)

Ratio of standard deviations = 0.542
Ratio of variances = 0.294

95% Confidence Intervals

                            CI for
         CI for StDev      Variance
Method       Ratio           Ratio
Bonett  (0.198, 1.412)  (0.039, 1.994)
Levene  (0.165, 1.367)  (0.027, 1.869)

Tests

                       Test
Method  DF1  DF2  Statistic  P-Value
Bonett    —    —          —    0.151
Levene    1   23       2.06    0.164
```

Neither of the nonparametric tests found the standard deviations to be 
significantly different. Knowing that data are normally distributed (if true)
provides useful information that leads to a test with a higher probability
of detecting differences between standard deviations (better 'power', in statistical terminology).  So if, you are
not able to say your data are normal, then you should plan for larger
sample sizes.

*Note: Sample size and power.* If you can give examples of the standard deviations that are typical in your
work and say roughly how what size difference between standard deviations would
be important to detect, then it might be possible to say what sample sizes
you would need in order to have, say, a 90% chance of detecting such a difference.

For example, here is a graph for a 2:1 ratio in standard deviations, using an F-test (normal data). It
indicates two samples of size around 24.

[image]

And for Levene's test, indicating sample sizes around 31.

[image]